# One Main Offsite Blog vs. Multiple Onsite Blogs

Tags: seo, domains, web-development, blog, multiple-domains

I work as the in-house SEO for an office refurbishment company. We are developing two sites:

```
Site 1: office refurbishment
Site 2: office furniture.
```

Here in lies my dilemma.

For SEO purposes, Should I run one main blog on a seperate domain that has content about office refurbishment and office furniture, or do I split the blogs up, i.e. site 1 has a blog on-site about office refurbishment and site 2 has a blog about office furniture.

If I run a blog off site I can subtly link the content to my other sites where necessary whilst still trying to provide good content. However, if I run my blogs on-site then I will get the authority and links to the blog added to my existing sites.

Has anybody got experience with this or any advice/answers for me?

Answer (score 2):

If the blog content(both kinds) is actually tied to the company, then I would create one on each site, tailored to that particular market, as it would seem that they do stand alone. Someone looking for furniture doesn't necessarily need work on their office. This keeps you from presenting visitors with stuff they don't care about, but also doesn't prevent you from cross-linking whenever it's appropriate.

If the blog content is primarily about the topics(or a wider umbrella "office stuff" topic), and *secondarily* about the company, then I think it'd be fine to have one off-site blog that occasionally references your services or whatever.

There's a [previous question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17254/sponsored-blog-or-explicit-owned/17255#17255) that doesn't involve exactly the same situation you're asking about, but brings up similar considerations, more on the side of the second case I describe above.

Answer (score 1):

My preference is usually to operate separate domains for separate business groups. For example, if a company had wholesale and retail groups, it would make sense to place these on different domains.

For SEO purposes, you'll hear a lot of debate about interlinking commonly owned sites. Some of the more Googlenoid will tell you not to do this. This may be true if you're operating a bunch of dodgy thin affiliate sites that Google wants to deindex anyway. But, if you're operating a group of legitimately related corporate sites this is fine to do and a common practice. You'll find many corporations do this quite successfully such as CBS Interactive, Icanhazcheezburger and even StackExchange.

You'll find that interlinking is most effective when you have an established site that has some authority. This will allow you to have newly launched sites rank quickly and they'll generally be stable unless the niche market is highly competitive. Linking two brand new sites won't be that effective so you should seek other outside links to help get them established.

Answer (score 0):

but when ever you contiguously linking two same sites then Google will watch suspiciously so if you pasted link to both sites then you have to link some other sites too in blog posts